# If Session state disabled in web config what is the impact on ViewBag, ViewData and Tempdata in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, web-config, session-state

If Session state disabled in `web.config` is there any impact on `ViewBag`, `ViewData` and `Tempdata` in MVC ?

Disable session state in web config by

```
pages enableSessionState="false"
```

Answer (score 3):

Only `TempData` is affected (as it relies on `Session`).

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711(v=vs.100).aspx)